# Pairwise exclusions

Tags: modeling, dataset, sas

I am running a logistic model on insurance data. I have a field agent gender which matters for a channel A (say) and doesn't matter for B. I want to put null values in case of B. The only thing I risk is exclusion by SAS (as SAS excludes every missing case by default). I heard that pairwise exclusion can solve my problem. Please tell me the following:

1. What is the difference between normal exclusion and pairwise exclusion?
2. How to do this is SAS?
3. What is listwise exclusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a missing data problem to me: it sounds like a question of model structure.

Distilling it to its essence, it seems you have two independent categorical variables gender ($X$, say) and "channel" ($Y$) and a binary response ($Z$).  Conceptually the model is

$$logit(\Pr(Z=1)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 Y + \varepsilon$$

when $Y$ = "A" and otherwise

$$logit(\Pr(Z=1)) = \beta_0 + \beta_2 Y + \varepsilon$$

when $Y \ne $ "A" (with parameters $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$ and zero-mean random error $\varepsilon$).  If this interpretation is correct, just set $X = 0$ in the data whenever $Y \ne $ "A".  This will cause such cases to have no effect on the value of $\beta_1$, which will be estimated solely from the other cases where $Y$ = "A".

Comment: +1 for actually solving his problem, as opposed to answering about missing data.

Comment: @richie Thanks.  The conversation initiated by your reply clued me in; so, as in many threads on this site, developing a solution is really a collaborative effort.  I look forward to the next replies which take our tentative first steps even further!

Comment: thanks..Agree. My concern is that "is placing a zero" there equal to placing a .( missing). Forgive my ignorance but I understand that 0 may give that an entirely new meaning. Lets say if I have a variable "agent's plcy rate"..and I give it a number 0 in place of missing doesnt it alter the meaning. ?? Just a thought that came to my mind.

Comment: @ayush That's exactly the issue.  If you put missing values in, the software has to skip those records and you lose information.  Normally it would be bad to just stick in zeros mindlessly.  That's why you have to do a little math.  If you want to be really convinced, write down the likelihood equations for the model.  The Chain Rule shows that $X$ multiplies $\beta_1$, so by setting $X=0$ appropriately you eliminate $\beta_1$ from all terms where it doesn't belong.  That's why 0 works and that's why *only* 0 works in this case.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main types of traditional treatments of missing data.
These are:
1) listwise
2) pairwise

Listwise is (from what you have said) the default in SAS. It means that you exclude any observation that has missing values in any of the terms in your model.
The advantage of this is that it ensures that all variables have the same n in the model. The disadvantage is that if you have one variable with a high proportion of missing data, much of the rest of the data can be ignored.

Pairwise, by contrast, only excludes cases where the value is missing for that particular variable. This has the advantage of keeping more data in the model that listwise does. However, the disadvantage is that some of your results will be based on different subsets of the data, and this can cause problems with p values and confidence intervals.

A better approach is probably multiple imputation where you attempt to predict the missing values using all of the data you have. This normally involves simulating a number of datasets with the missing data filled in, and then performing all analyses on each of the datasets individually, and averaging the results.

A good paper on treatment of missing data is Graham 2009 [Missing Data: Making it work in the real world](http://www.iapsych.com/articles/graham2009.pdf) which goes into much more detail than I have here. You also need to determine if the missingness in your data is random or not, as if the probability of missingness depends on exogenous variables to your dataset, then none of these approaches will work correctly.

A good resource on multiple imputation is [here](http://www.multiple-imputation.com/)

[This](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/missing.htm) article on missing data in SAS may prove helpful, or someone else may answer as to how to do this in SAS.

Comment: thanks..I am not much concerned about missing value imputations..nor can I do many analysis and then average them..Basically as I said, I have 5 channels. 1 channel out of those have right values..for the rest 4 channels, I need to fill missing in those variables. My concern is , how to tell SAS that dont delete these variables, these are created deliberately by me as actually it doesnt make any business sense to have agent characteristics for those 4 channels..Hope you got my point..or any setting in which I can tell SAS that dont delete missing values.